# Should the charity and charitable-contributions tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[charity](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity) seems to be applied to all questions that somehow relate to charity, while two out of the three questions tagged with [charitable-contributions](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charitable-contributions) deal specifically with tax issues. Should these be merged or left how they are? If they're merged, my opinion would be to preserve the more general [charity](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity) tag and accompany tax issues with relevant country tags and the [taxes](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxes) tag.

Comment: It's only tangentially related, but is there a better place (chat? one large meta question?) to ask about tag merges? If I get on a fix-the-tags kick in the future and notice a whole slew of other tags ([it's happened before](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/q/751/7590)) it seems tedious to post a new meta question for each one. However, that might be preferable because it allows for more detailed discussion on each suggestion, and I don't always have the rep to suggest tag synonyms on tags that aren't used as much.

Comment: In general, changes need to be recorded so that they can be found with relative ease.  Please resist the urge to gather unrelated changes together.  Discussion is indeed the goal and globing several items together into one post makes that difficult.  So, um...carry on? ;)

Comment: @GeorgeMarian That was my intuition. Separate meta posts it is.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest we keep the [charitable-contributions](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charitable-contributions) tag for those questions specifically about contributing to a charity, and the [charity](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity) tag for anything else about charity not specifically involving making a charitable contribution.  In other words, questions tagged [charitable-contribution](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charitable-contribution) shouldn't also require the [charity](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity) tag.

Consequently, many existing questions tagged [charity](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity) would need to be re-tagged as [charitable-contributions](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charitable-contributions).

IMHO, I wouldn't want to lose the "contribution" concept by having one and only one [charity](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity) tag.

Mind you, now that I'm thinking about it, why isn't it called `charitable-donations` instead?  What's the more idiomatic expression - a "charitable contributions" or a "charitable donations", or are they equally common?  There are search engine ramifications.

Comment: Good question. A quick search turned up [this article](http://subfictional.com/2012/05/03/donation-vs-contribution-payment-processors-the-irs-and-your-organization/), which discusses how some payment processors see the terms a little differently. In the context of donor-advised funds, the term "charitable grants" is sometimes used too. It's definitely less common, though.

Comment: @JohnBensin BTW, while we're discussing tags: You don't need to remove single-use tags. The system will eventually purge a tag that is only used once ([source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121191/what-are-all-the-reasons-a-tag-can-be-eliminated-automatically)). I'm referring to your edit to remove "diamonds" from http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23436/what-is-the-secondary-market-like-for-diamond-jewelry .. the system process that removes low usage tags won't bump the questions unnecessarily.

Comment: Oh, it removes tags that are only used once? For some reason I thought it only removed tags that weren't used at all. Thanks for letting me know.